Does Linux / Ubuntu support usb-c replicators with Ethernet integrated in monitors like Samsung ViewFinity S6
Monitors like Samsung ViewFinity S6 have integrated usb-c hubs that provide connectors like 3 USB port, audio line out, ethernet and display link out for daisy chaining, so you only need a laptop that has usb-c and connect it using only this cable that also provides the power for the notebook.
The operating system like Linux needs drivers to support these connector. I generally do  find few information about how operating system access these connectors. Are they very "generic" so that operating system support by Linux like Ubuntu is very good and so nobody mentions it?
